# TPP spawn Roblox studio

Tags: roblox

I'm wondering if its possible to add Spawn locations only for experience teleported players.
let me explain.. i join game A and get teleported to game B But what i want is that when i get teleported from game A to B that in game B i spawn at a difrent location than the location for players that just joined Game B. can someone help me whit this idk any code that can do this

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use [`TeleportAsync`](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/TeleportService#TeleportAsync) instead of `Teleport` (you should), you can create a [`TeleportOptions`](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/TeleportOptions) instance using `Instance.new`. I also assume that the SpawnLocation is not too special, because this way of doing it is exploitable. A safer but also more complicated way of doing this is using [Memory Stores](https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/data/memory-stores).

Using the first way mentioned, a `TeleportOptions` instance has two functions you can use to achieve this: [`GetTeleportData`](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/TeleportOptions#GetTeleportData) and [`SetTeleportData`](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/TeleportOptions#SetTeleportData).

You would have two spawn point indicating parts. They should be floating, so that people won't get stuck in the middle of the floor. Make sure to anchor them.

You would then have a script calling [`Player:GetJoinData`](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Player#GetJoinData) when they join. If there is relevant data, you should teleport the player to one part, whereas other data would teleport the player to the other part.

In pseudo-code:

```lua
players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    if not player.Character then player.CharacterAdded:Wait() end
    local part = workspace.SpawnPartNormal
    if player:GetJoinData().TeleportData.TeleportedFromGameA then
        part = workspace.SpawnPartFromGameA
    end
    move_characterof_to(player, part)
end)
```

The safer way of doing it will unfortunately not work if the two places are not of the same experience (game). Here is the safer way:

```lua
local store = memorystoreserv:GetSortedStore("PlayerFromGameA")

players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    if not player.Character then player.CharacterAdded:Wait() end
    local part = workspace.SpawnPartNormal
    if store:GetAsync(player.UserId) then
        part = workspace.SpawnPartFromGameA
    end
    move_characterof_to(player, part)
end)
```

Both of these are nearly identical. In the safer one, I used a `MemoryStoreSortedMap` object's [`GetAsync`](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/MemoryStoreSortedMap#GetAsync) function.

Comment: Just to help you, this is the place used for commenting!

Comment: This is pseudo-code (not really, but can be considered as so), which means that you need to make your own structure. `TeleportData` is the teleportation data used - When you teleport the player, you should use `SetTeleportData` like I mentioned, and then we get a player's `TeleportData`. `TeleportedFromGameA` is a placeholder name, it can be anything. Make sure to set that when using `SetTeleportData`!

Comment: You should be using a `Script`, not a `LocalScript`. `Script`s are server sided. I would recommend you to read [this guide](https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/networking/client-server-model) to understand the Client-Server model. You definitely should read that, but in a nutshell, the server is a computer connecting all clients together and holding the base of the game.